# How do I write a query in google bigquery to infer the data type of a column?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with all string columns, but I know certain columns are numbers (or dates). Is there a built in function in BigQuery to infer the data type of individual columns? Something like select is_string(column_name) from table_name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea that comes to mind is using `SAFE_CAST` in combination with `LOGICAL_AND`, e.g.:

```
#standardSQL
WITH T AS (
  SELECT '2017-05-01' AS x, '3.14' AS y, '5' AS z UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-03-02' AS x, '1.59' AS y, '-1' AS z UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL AS x, NULL AS y, NULL AS z
)
SELECT
  LOGICAL_AND(x IS NULL OR SAFE_CAST(x AS DATE) IS NOT NULL) AS x_is_date,
  LOGICAL_AND(y IS NULL OR SAFE_CAST(y AS FLOAT64) IS NOT NULL) AS y_is_float64,
  LOGICAL_AND(z IS NULL OR SAFE_CAST(z AS TIMESTAMP) IS NOT NULL) AS z_is_timestamp
FROM T;
```

This results in true, true, and false (the `z` values are not timestamps). If you want to reuse the same expression multiple times, you can make this a little less verbose with a SQL UDF:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION IsDate(x STRING) AS (
  x IS NULL OR SAFE_CAST(x AS DATE) IS NOT NULL
);

WITH T AS (
  SELECT '2017-05-01' AS x, '3.14' AS y, '5' AS z UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-03-02' AS x, '1.59' AS y, '-1' AS z UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL AS x, NULL AS y, NULL AS z
)
SELECT
  LOGICAL_AND(IsDate(x)) AS x_is_date,
  LOGICAL_AND(IsDate(y)) AS y_is_date,
  LOGICAL_AND(IsDate(z)) AS z_is_date
FROM T;
```

This results in true, false, false, since only `x` has values in date format.